# Need help in nested array concept

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nested array query. I need data in a particular format. It's working fine just needs to know a better way of doing it. I have to plot a graph.

Data comes from API in this format:

```
[
  {
    company: 'BMW',
    cMin: 20,
    cMax: 100,
    vMin: 30,
    vMax: 90,
  },
  {
    company: 'Audi',
    cMin: 10,
    cMax: 90,
    vMin: 10,
    vMax: 80,
  },
]
```

What I have tried!

```js
const cRed = { name: 'C Red', data: [] };
const cGreen = { name: 'C Green', data: [] };
const vRed = { name: 'V Red', data: [] };
const vGreen = { name: 'V Green', data: [] };

dataset.forEach((e) => {
  cRed.data.push(e.cMin);
  cGreen.data.push(e.cMax);
  vRed.data.push(e.vMin);
  vGreen.data.push(e.vMax);
});

const all = [cRed, cGreen, vRed, vRed];

console.log(all);
```

Expected result:

```
[ 
  { name: 'C Red', data: [ 20, 10 ] },
  { name: 'C Green', data: [ 100, 90 ] },
  { name: 'V Red', data: [ 30, 10 ] },
  { name: 'V Red', data: [ 30, 10 ] } 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create one object and use it for name mapping and then use `reduce` to create object and use `Object.values` on that object as a final result.

```js
const data = [{"company":"BMW","cMin":20,"cMax":100,"vMin":30,"vMax":90},{"company":"Audi","cMin":10,"cMax":90,"vMin":10,"vMax":80}]

const map = {
  cMin: 'C Red',
  cMax: 'C Green',
  vMin: 'V Red',
  vMax: 'V Green'
}

const obj = data.reduce((r, { company, ...rest }) => {
  Object.entries(rest).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (key in map) {
      if (!r[key]) r[key] = {
        name: map[key],
        data: []
      }
      r[key].data.push(value)
    }
  })
  return r;
}, {})

const result = Object.values(obj)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is just fine other than that the names you use when creating `all` aren't the same as the ones you're filling (`vosRed` instead of `cRed`, etc.). Although with ES2015+, any time you have a `forEach`, you can consider using `for-of`, which you may find easier to read (or may not). Also if you like, you can use destructuring.

Here's an example using both (this replaces the `forEach`):

```
for (const {cMin, cMax, vMin, vMax} of dataset) {
  cRed.data.push(cMin);
  cGreen.data.push(cMax);
  vRed.data.push(vMin);
  vGreen.data.push(vMax);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const dataset = [
  {
    company: 'BMW',
    cMin: 20,
    cMax: 100,
    vMin: 30,
    vMax: 90,
  },
  {
    company: 'Audi',
    cMin: 10,
    cMax: 90,
    vMin: 10,
    vMax: 80,
  },
];

const cRed = { name: 'C Red', data: [] };
const cGreen = { name: 'C Green', data: [] };
const vRed = { name: 'V Red', data: [] };
const vGreen = { name: 'V Green', data: [] };

for (const {cMin, cMax, vMin, vMax} of dataset) {
  cRed.data.push(cMin);
  cGreen.data.push(cMax);
  vRed.data.push(vMin);
  vGreen.data.push(vMax);
}

const all = [cRed, cGreen, vRed, vGreen];

console.log(all);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If `dataset` isn't massive, another approach is to use `map` to loop through it repeatedly (once for `cRed`, again for `vRed`, ...):

```
const all = [
  {name: 'C Red',   data: dataset.map(({cMin}) => cMin)},
  {name: 'C Green', data: dataset.map(({cMax}) => cMax)},
  {name: 'V Red',   data: dataset.map(({vMin}) => vMin)},
  {name: 'V Green', data: dataset.map(({vMax}) => vMax)}
];
```

That replaces the creation of `cRed` et. al., the `forEach`, **and** the creation of `all` at the end.

Live Example:

```js
const dataset = [
  {
    company: 'BMW',
    cMin: 20,
    cMax: 100,
    vMin: 30,
    vMax: 90,
  },
  {
    company: 'Audi',
    cMin: 10,
    cMax: 90,
    vMin: 10,
    vMax: 80,
  },
];

const all = [
  {name: 'C Red',   data: dataset.map(({cMin}) => cMin)},
  {name: 'C Green', data: dataset.map(({cMax}) => cMax)},
  {name: 'V Red',   data: dataset.map(({vMin}) => vMin)},
  {name: 'V Green', data: dataset.map(({vMax}) => vMax)}
];

console.log(all);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Again, though, it makes four passes through the data instead of just one, so not appropriate for a really massive dataset (hundreds of thousands or millions of records).